# How to InsertUI in a modularized shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build an application, where the user can add a piece of UI (in this case an input text field) by clicking a button. As this is only part of a bigger application, I wish to use modules to keep structure in my project.

However, my text field won't show after clicking the action button. I'm using the new function `moduleServer()` that was recently introduced by `shiny`.

Here is a reprex

```
library(shiny)

ModularizedUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidPage(
    # Input: Action button to add text field
    actionButton(inputId = ns("add_text"),
                 label = "Add text field"),
  )
}

ModularizedServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- session$ns
      
      # Track the number of input boxes to render for test training
      counter_text <- reactiveVal(0)
      
      # Input/Output fields for start dates test training
      observeEvent(input$add_text, {
        
        counter_text(counter_text() + 1)
        
        # Add UI if this button is clicked
        insertUI(
          selector = "#add",
          where = "afterEnd",
          ui = textInput(inputId = ns(paste0("textfield_", counter_text())), 
                         label = "New text")
        )
      })
    }
  )
}

ui <- navbarPage("Dashboard",
                 tabPanel("Text fields",
                          ModularizedUI(id = "Text_Fields")
                 )
                 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ModularizedServer("Text_Fields")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave `insertUI` the selector `#add`, which defines where the new elements have to be inserted. But there is no element with id `#add` in your UI.

Add `div(id = '#add')` after your `actionButton` and it should work.

(I would then use `where = beforeEnd`, so that all Inputs are inside that new `div` and can be easily targeted using CSS or JS, or....)

Complete example:

```
library(shiny)

ModularizedUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidPage(
    # Input: Action button to add text field
    actionButton(inputId = ns("add_text"),
                 label = "Add text field"),
    div(id = "add")
  )
}

ModularizedServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      
      # Track the number of input boxes to render for test training
      counter_text <- reactiveVal(0)
      
      # Input/Output fields for start dates test training
      observeEvent(input$add_text, {
        counter_text(counter_text() + 1)
        
        # Add UI if this button is clicked
        insertUI(
          selector = "#add",
          where = "beforeEnd",
          ui = textInput(inputId = ns(paste0("textfield_", counter_text())), 
                         label = "New text")
        )
      })
    }
  )
}

ui <- navbarPage("Dashboard",
                 tabPanel("Text fields",
                          ModularizedUI(id = "Text_Fields")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ModularizedServer("Text_Fields")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `Id = 'add'` without hash.

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm facing the next problem: my generated `inputId` seems to be undefined. Therefore, the UI works, but I cannot assign any server logic to it. Any ideas?

Comment: In general: new problem -> new question. When I use the observer `observeEvent(input$add_text, { print(input$textfield_1)  })` inside the module server it works fine.